# Replace date from message to @timestamp in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have this log http://wklej.org/id/2777228/ and i want date from this log to be timestamp. My config file:

http://wklej.org/id/2777231/

But thid ont work. http://wklej.org/id/2777230/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I tried and it worked for me:

```
filter {
    grok{
         match => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:myTimestamp}"}
        }
    date {
            locale => "en"
            match => ["myTimestamp", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS", "ISO8601"]
            timezone => "Europe/Warsaw"
            add_field => { "debug" => "timestampMatched"}
        }
}
```

Output:

```
  "_source": {
    "message": "2016-08-03 10:19:44,503 [DEBUG] NHibernate.SQL: SELECT this_.ID as ID6_0_, this_.Valor as Valor6_0_, this_.ANALYTIC_DATA_ID as ANALYTIC3",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-08-03T08:19:44.503Z",
    "host": "RST-Mrunal",
    "myTimestamp": "2016-08-03 10:19:44,503",
    "debug": "timestampMatched"
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I found this solution but in you and my case @timestamp is diffrent than myTimestamp. I want timestamp = myTimestamp

Comment: in above solution @timestamp = myTimestamp.

Comment: The default target of date plugin is `@timestamp`.

Comment: edit: xd oh my god,  forget timezone or something this working :)

Comment: unable to understand your comment. What are you trying to say?

Comment: thanks for help, i forget my timestamp have wrong timezone, so your solution is working, thx :)

Comment: can you help me if i want 2 target? target=> myTimestamp and @timestamp ?